# psycopg - INSERT gzipped data into bytea column

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to gzip a string and then write it into a `bytea` column using [psycopg2](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/).

**table:**

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  data bytea
)
```

**insert:**

```
import psycopg2

data = "some string".encode("zlib") # 'x\x9c+\xce\xcfMU(.)\xca\xccK\x07\x00\x1ak\x04l'

conn = psycopg2.connect("my parameters")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO public.test VALUES (%s)", (data,))

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    psycopg2.DataError: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x9c
```

is this an issue with the library? Do I need to change the encoding somehow? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to insert binary data into the database, you will need to use the psycopg2.Binary() wrapper.  Using a string like you've done will cause the data to be treated as text, which will either be rejected due to encoding issues, or accepted but mangled when you try to read it again.

Try replacing the last execute call with:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO public.test VALUES (%s)", (psycopg2.Binary(data),))
```

Comment: does this work for a single field or just for the whole row ?

Comment: There is nothing stopping you providing multiple `psycopg2.Binary` type positional parameters.  It is just the standard Python DB-API.